# Initial mysql data not loaded from docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am a new-bee to docker world. I am trying to create a mysql container with some initial scripts but these are not loaded after starting the docker service. I can see all the .sql files are loaded in **docker-entrypoint-initdb.d** folder of the container but no data loaded on DB after startup. No errors in logs.

my docker-compose file

```
services:
  test-mysql-service:
    image: mysql:5.7.15
    container_name: test-mysql-container
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_db 
      MYSQL_USER: docker
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypassword
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypassword
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    volumes:
      - /home/jerin/dumps/Dump20200519:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:rw
    networks:
      - test-network
```

Comment: How can you tell the data isn't getting loaded?  Does anything interesting show up in the container logs?

Comment: Hi David Thank you for the response. There  are no errors in log other than SSL context.  I can see  'test-mysql-container     | Database initialized' , test-mysql-container     | MySQL init process done. Ready for start up., test-mysql-container     | 2020-05-25T14:22:35.348204Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
test-mysql-container     | Version: '5.7.15'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)